# Representing a number as an unordered list of smaller numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics, restricted-complexity, encoding

Suppose we want to encode a large integer \$x\$ as a list of words in such a way that the decoder can recover \$x\$ regardless of the order in which the words are received. Using lists of length \$k\$ and a dictionary of \$n\$ words, there are \$\binom{n+k-1}k\$ different multisets possible ([why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751384/number-of-multisets)), so we should be able to represent values of \$x\$ from \$1\$ through \$\binom{n+k-1}k\$.

This is a code golf challenge to implement such an encoder and decoder (as separate programs or functions); your golf score is the total code length. Any sensible/conventional input & output formats are allowed.

Encode: Given positive integers \$n,k,x\$ with \$x\le\binom{n+k-1}k\$, encode \$x\$ as a list of \$k\$ integers between \$1\$ and \$n\$ (inclusive).

Decode: Given \$n\$ and a list of \$k\$ integers between \$1\$ and \$n\$, output the decoded message \$x\$.

Correctness requirement: If `encode(n,k,x)` outputs \$L\$ and \$\operatorname{sort}(L)=\operatorname{sort}(M)\$, then `decode(n,M)` outputs \$x\$.

**Runtime requirement**: Both operations must run in [polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polynomial_time) with respect to the length of \$x\$ in bits. This is meant to rule out impractical brute-force solutions that just enumerate all the multisets.

Comment: Your restricted complexity requirement is perfectly legitimate, but impractical brute-force solutions and code-golf are actually good ol' friends. :-)

Comment: I admit I'm less interested in the byte-level golf and more interested in seeing simple practical algorithms for this problem! Should I change the post in some way to reflect this?

Comment: @Karl codegolf and simple/practical are pretty much mutually exclusive. If you are interested in the latter I suggest you drop the `codegolf` tag. Or rather I would suggest it if there weren't already an answer.

Comment: Is there a reason that you expect this to be possible within the complexity constraint of polynomial in the bit-length of \$x\$? I think the most efficient algorithm will be much like those on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Finding_the_k-combination_for_a_given_number with tweaks to cater for repeats, which I don't _think_ will be.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 258 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
P=cumprod;p=prod
def e(x,k):r=r_[:k]+1;f=p(r);X=x*f-f;i=int(X**(1/k));Q=P([1,*i+r]);Q[-2::-1]*=P(i+1-r);j=sum(Q<=X);x-=Q[j-1]//f;k-=1;return*(1//k*[x]or e(x,k)),j+i-k
d=lambda L,j=1:1+sum([p(s-1+r_[:j])//p(r_[1:(j:=j+1)])for s in sort(L)])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVBLTsMwEBUscwov_VUwC1TZzA26aHeVrKgKJAY7JLGcRErPwqYbuBOcBlspI43mzTzN05v5_A6X-X0crtevZbZi93t3b-PYo2HpwwW5PoxxpsUBXlMfx0YHyKVoWotavPKOqAjxbFRXMaktBByJPsFKrbDagRtmfKIUy7IjRB_hgI3k1LFYpc6IR6WErGgaOyZF2vQwLT0-PsOJ6FXA0fjEl6XVnQCpYzsvcchqZUfNWo3x5oFwz5zoigY-6v6lqdGee5BKsqxmAp6EZNmkr0hZJotnIxX2CjyTpCI26UzIDWhKt-J9mmyv-IHMuMzEenhrseTyYYsbIKpAIeYjHW9TPhHe4A2Qm8j_X_8A)

Two functions `e` and `d` for encoding and decoding: We do not use or accept parameter `n` since it is not needed (because using the "natural" encoding different `n` will give the same result provided they are large enough).

Multisets are represented as sorted sequences; the decoder also accepts unsorted input.

With `n` eliminated it actually makes sense to talk about complexity in `x` because now `x` can grow without bound.

I'll assume fixed `k` and that all basic operations including taking the `kth` root are polynomial in the bit length of their operands. As `k` is fixed this will also hold for all factorials and binomial coefficients the functions use.

#### How?

Decoding is easy since it amounts to summing a couple of binomial coefficients.

Encoding is a bit more tricky as we need to invert binomial coefficients (in `n`, `k` is fixed) to make this constant in terms of basic operations we use the simple inequality

\$n^\underline k \le n^k \le n^\overline k\$

where the underline and overline denote falling and rising factorials.

To find the largest `n` such that

\$\begin{pmatrix}n+k-1 \\ k \end{pmatrix}\le x\$

we take the `kth` root of `k!x` and then brute force check all rising factorials whose terms "pass" through the value obtained, `k` in total.

Comment: Apologies for my mistake and the previous comments and thank you for taking the time to respond to them!

Comment: @Hunaphu no worries. Good to see you figured it out in the end.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 80 + 31 = 111 bytes

### Encoder, 80 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≔⁰ζ≔⁰ε≔¹δＷ¬›δη«≔δε≦⊕ζ≔÷×δ⁺ζθζδ»Ｆ⮌…⁰θ«Ｗ›εη«≦⊖ζ≔÷×εζ⁺ζ⊕ιε»⟦Ｉζ⟧≧⁻εη¿ι≔÷×ε⊕ι⁺ζιε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY89a8MwEIZn@1doPIELCR07lQZKhoRgupUMqnWxDmw5lmQXHPzbXSm2GyeQ8b2v57lMCZNVohiGrT43bt@UP2ig5m/xMiuf362lXMMqYd1dwltaJ0z69KuoQAb7ysGnQeH8AZkwxTlnlziaZuW4Ge3EeapsdWawRO1Qjozov@E21JJE@KISbVg9FI2FLmE152F25PbxqTIMUmzRWIRU6ByDYT2RJ6/ZCa9OobGQ2OCjxDMLHMGzycIeiAet63t9HB0MaQffH8I66Pjx7umUcuVgR7qxfiEI@S6dmD/BnnMfWDcJmrn9MLzG69Xw0hZ/) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Takes `k` and `x` as inputs. Explanation: Port of the `sord` function from [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1370461/30622), but outputs the values in reverse order since it's golfier.

### Decoder, 31 bytes

```
Ｗ⁻θυＦ№θ⌊ι⊞υ⌊ιＩΣＥυ÷Π…·ι⁺ικΠ…·¹⊕κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYwxC8IwEIV3f0XGK0RQHDvWpUMh6Fg6hPS0h2miSa7@/Ji4Cd5yvO99PLPoYLy2Ob8XsihgIMcRXlJw04ibDwI6zy5VUipaeQVqSqU4LsA/sN2pQEXtdExwLWzQz6r0Lp1poxlBBT@zSdA7YznShhft7ggkhSq5/kfZLum/d6xbJuCKLuEM1f1em/M4HqQ4SXGYprzf7Ac) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Takes a list of `k` integers as input. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁻θυＦ№θ⌊ι⊞υ⌊ι
```

Sort the integers.

```
ＩΣＥυ÷Π…·ι⁺ικΠ…·¹⊕κ
```

Apply the `ords` algorithm from [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1363513/30622).

Comment: Isn't the `sord` function O(x^{1/k}) which is not polynomial in the bit length of x? I can't read charcoal, so I looked at the math SE code instead. (I was curious because efficient inversion of the binomial coefficient was what I got stuck at at my own attempts.)

Comment: @loopywalt The Math.SE question asks for the most efficient algorithm. I just assumed that it would be good enough for this question...

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 283 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
i=fromIntegral
p=product
m=map
s=succ
t=pred
f n=p[1..n]
a k n=p[n..n+k-1]`div`f k
b k x=t$until((>x).a k)s$floor((i$x*f k)**(1/i k))
d _ _[]=0
d k n(e:f)=a k e+d(k-1)e f
e 1 n x=[x]
e k n x|let m=b k x=m:e(k-1)m(x-a k m)
c k n=(m s.e k n.t,s.d k n.m t.reverse.sort)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVC7bsMwDNz1FRw8SHmoMbIFVaYuBfoHhpGolpQKlmRDogMP/XeXdocu3Y7k8Y7HL116G8Ky@DgOGeFNo5YfviDzyuUhvie0j6wDG9WYBzN1yKKKemRFlanrGFLbGuYgqbGppUwt09BvVaJq3x/r9m788@6gZ580mRVWU0IfOL/OQhJZlMqFYcic@2reEU/sdrx@8QQEM3CDW9OqEyGS5fbihFod7N5wEhcWHLNQQyLlZm4J9yv@DhYhql/HeLEbN/L5uO5GwbrtSB6hyG1D4qHIzUJGQJnt0@ZiZaGfiCVqT4GyT8hdQd7BGc7itbqugetTeyjJ/DX/Y4jlBw)